# How to create a "nested" color palette in R?

Tags: r, plot, colors, color-palette

I am trying to create a color palette in `R` with more than 80 levels/classes in order to create a graph with over 1000 data points. The palette should be of a nested style: basically, the 80 levels are nested within 15 higher hierarchical levels (these are taxonomic ranks) and I would like each lower level to be of a similar color but different shade than the higher level in the palette:

```
    Var1 Var2            Desired Output
    name1 name1.1        yellow
    name1 name1.2        yellow1
    name2 name2.1        darkblue1
    name2 name2.2        darkblue2
    name2 name2.3        darkblue3
        .                 .
        .                 .
        .                 .
    name15 name15.1      gold1
    name15 name15.2      gold2
```

How to go about this? I know `ColorRampPalette` but all the higher levels do not have the same number of lower levels.

Comment: There is the `colors()` function. For example, `colors()[grep("red",colors())]`.

Comment: Thanks for your input. So you suggest writing a function to achieve what I want? I've found [this method](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14862469/2842348) as well which is perhaps easier than what you propose. But I'm worried I've missed any automated way of doing this in `ggplot2`/`lattice`.

Comment: I suggest nothing. I just provide you a function listing all the colors available on R. It also provides you the names the way you want to create them (basically, color name + integer). If you found something fittinq your request, it would be easier.